# jquery.jscroll not working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, infinite-scroll

I am trying to make infinite scroll in my page but its not working pretty well with me. The below is the whole code I have implemented for infinite scroll. Its just started loading all the data at once when the below code is implemented. Infinite scrolling is not working properly for it.

Main View

```
 <div class="scroll">
                @Html.Partial("_Products")
            </div>
<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jquery.jscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.scroll').jscroll({
            autoTrigger: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
Function PartialViewData(category_id As String, order_by As String, group_name As String) As ActionResult
            ViewBag.lstProducts = gController.CategoryProducts(category_id, order_by)
            Return PartialView("_Products")
        End Function
```

_Products.vbhtml. This is a partial view

```
@For Each MostViewed In ViewBag.lstProducts
    @<div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="single-item">
            @If MostViewed.ItemTag <> "" Then
                @<div class="ribbon-wrapper"><div style="background-color:@MostViewed.ItemTagColor;" class="ribbon">@MostViewed.ItemTag</div></div>
            End If

            <div class="single-item-header wrapper">
                <a href="/Product/Index?id=@MostViewed.SKUID"><img src="@MostViewed.ItemImageUrl" class="image270320" alt="@MostViewed.ItemShortDesc"></a>
                <div class="description">
                    <div class="description_content">
                        @MostViewed.ItemShortDesc
                        <a class="add-to-cart pull-right" href="/ShoppingCart/AddToCart?sku_code=@MostViewed.SKUID"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart shopcart"></i></a>
                        <a class="add-to-cart pull-right" href="/FavouriteList/AddToWishList?sku_code=@MostViewed.SKUID"><i class="fa fa-heart favorlist"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="single-item-body">
                <p class="single-item-title">
                    @MostViewed.SKUID
                </p>
                <p class="single-item-price">
                    @If MostViewed.ItemDiscountedPrice <> "" Then
                        @<span class="flash-del">@Request.Cookies("currency_code").Value.ToString @Math.Round(Val(Request.Cookies("currency_rate").Value.ToString) * MostViewed.ItemOrignalPrice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)</span>
                        @<span class="flash-sale">@Request.Cookies("currency_code").Value.ToString @Math.Round(Val(Request.Cookies("currency_rate").Value.ToString) * MostViewed.ItemDiscountedPrice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)</span>
                    Else
                        @<span>@Request.Cookies("currency_code").Value.ToString @Math.Round(Val(Request.Cookies("currency_rate").Value.ToString) * MostViewed.ItemOrignalPrice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)</span>
                    End If

                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    Next
  <a href="/Product/PartialViewData?category_id=@Request.QueryString("category_id")&order_by=@Request.QueryString("order_by")&group_name=@Request.QueryString("group_name")">next page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the solution for above problem its just because of id of

```
<a href="/Product/PartialViewData?category_id=@Request.QueryString("category_id")&order_by=@Request.QueryString("order_by")&group_name=@Request.QueryString("group_name")">next page</a>
```

Once I set this for different id every time it starts working

```
 <a id="@ViewBag.PageNo" href="/Product/PartialViewData?category_id=@Request.QueryString("category_id")&order_by=@Request.QueryString("order_by")&group_name=@Request.QueryString("group_name")">next page</a>
```

`ViewBag.PageNo` Changes everytime whenever my data is loaded

Comment: It doesn't solve for me, do you have another solution?

Comment: @Phoenix_uy can you post your question so I can have a look at it